# TypeError when trying to open /dev/hidraw0 from python script

Tags: python, usb

I'm trying to read some data from a USB HID device with some basic python code, on a Raspberry Pi, but keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "gnome1.py", line 2, in <module>
fd = open("/dev/hidraw0", os.O_RDWR|os.O_NONBLOCK) 
TypeError: file() argument 2 must be string, not int
```

This is the Python code:

```
import os, sys
fd = open("/dev/hidraw0", os.O_RDWR|os.O_NONBLOCK)
os.write(fd, "QPI\xBE\xAC\r")
os.read(fd, 512)
```

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: See the documentation of `open` and you'll see you're passing an integer to the argument of the reading mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fd = os.open("/dev/hidraw0", os.O_RDWR|os.O_NONBLOCK)